# C# How to call a derived methods?

Tags: c#, methods, overriding, derived

I have a situation where I want to call only one method and have all the methods its derived from called also.

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void Method()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Derived1 : Base
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        base.Method();
        // Do something
    }
}

public class Derived2 : Derived1
{
    public override void Method()
    {
        base.Method();
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I want to only call Derived2.Method() and have all the Methods() called that it derives from
The issue with the way I currently have it set up is that Derived1.Method() never gets called.

Is there a way to make the called method call all the previous instances of it in a derived class?

Comment: `Derived1.Method()` does get called in the code you posted. Put a debug point or a logging statement in Derived1.Method(), and you will see that it is getting invoked.

Comment: Proof: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3aQUIm